# Pseudo-external links and SEO

Tags: seo, links, google-search, web-crawlers

I don't know, how to name such a links.

Main idea is following:

I write a post at a community, which I do not control, and place a link to my web-site:

> www.mywebsite.com

When post is saved, my link is converted to this:

> `http://www.some-community.com/outgoing?http://mywebsite.com`

It does't have "nofollow" attribute value.

When i click this link, i get notification page, like this:

> "You are going to follow to external site. Continue ?"

This page contains the actual link to my website, again without "nofollow".

How such a pseudo-external link will be handled by Google's and other search engines? I think, this will be no problems with reaching my website, but extra hop. Or?

Will posting a link on such communities increase ranking of my website?

**Update 1**

Just rephrasing my question:

I promote my website in some communities via writing posts (with links to my website).

These communities having such redirect notifications, like "You are visiting external site. Continue ?".

The question is - will using such communities increase my ranking ?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of having such a pseudo-external page is to avoid passing pagerank to other sites. If you can´t find noindex and/or nofollow tags inside the page maybe they are using javascript for adding the link and hiding it from robots, it would be easy, your url is contained in the pseudo-external url.

What happens if you disable JS in your browser? Does the link still appears in the page? If not surely you won't get any pagerank from there.

Comment: Yes, in notification page, i see direct link to external website, having JavaScript disabled. This link is without "nofollow, noindex" attributes. Does it seems like a good sign ?

Comment: You should disable javascript before you get into pseudo-external page; while you are looking your comment (where you posted your website url), disable javascript, click your posted link to get into pseudo-external page, if You still see your link there and you'd checked all recommendations John Conde gave you, then you are surely getting some pagerank.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines do follow and can count a redirected link to your website as a link assuming the redirect script is not blocked and the redirect is a 301 or 302. There may be other headers that work as well but these are how it is typically done anyway.

So check:

- to see if the redirect is blocked via robots.txt
- see if the redirect script uses the x-robots-tag and is noindex, nofollow
- check what redirect header code is sent out and make sure it is a 301 or 302

Comment: In notification page, I should  manually click the link to my website. Also, in web inspector, i don't see any event listeners, attached to the link. Am I right, that there will be no problems with redirect script, because no scripts are used at all ?

Comment: The redirect and headers would be done by the server side redirect script. You'll need to use Firebug or a similar tool to view those headers and what response code is actually used. Click on the link and see what it says.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're talking about, but I think you just need to change
`www.mywebsite.com` into `http://www.mywebsite.com`

Comment: Presumably there's some reason why AontonAL wants to have that extra page in the middle, so just bypassing that extra page isn't a solution.

Comment: @paulmorriss, you misunderstood me. I promote my website in some communities via writing posts (with links to my website). These comminities having such notifications, like "You are visiting external site. Continue ?".

Comment: see Update 1 in my question

Comment: I understand now, you have no control over what those communities are doing.